# constraint Problem /Solution in sqlServer

Tags: sql-server-2005, foreign-keys, constraints

Sorry for my shallow  question . 
Imagine I have 4 Tables in my  DataBase (SQLServer 2005). 
**Picture** , **News** , **product** and  **gallery** Tables . At my Picture Table i Have 3 foreign key to all 3 other tables , And all foreign keys are nullable and default value = -1 . All tables have Primary keys and is Identity .

At my webform every photo that i insert is related to **one** , **two** or **three** other tables .
 **example**  : it could be related to NewsId =4 , galleryId= 2 and not related to Product Table . So ProductId = -1. 
  
I don't know how to insert photo and not give this error **"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Picture_Product" "** 
 . 
I know why is that , and that's because of **inforce FOREIGN KEY constraint** . But i don't know how to design my DataBase in order overcome  this problem .I hope i could come it across .

**p.s**:In addition in future i want query my Picture table according News , Product or Gallery or mixed of them .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you don't have any product with the ID -1, you have to set the default value at NULL and insert null value instead of -1

When you create a foreign key, the sql server check that the inserted foreign key exists in the referenced table, in you case it doesn't exists so the RDMS refuses to insert the row.

Comment: thank you , How can i assign null to foreignkeys , for example in my Picture Object i have : private int _productId ; and it automatically get  0 value if i don't assign value .

Comment: you can set it as nullable :

private int? _productID

if you're working with c#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

why use `-1` for undefined? that is what NULL is for!  delete the default and allow those rows to have NULL when there is no FK row.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a default value of -1 for your foreign keys? When you insert a new row that doesn't populate one of the foreign keys, then the foreign key will be set to -1 which doesn't match the keyof a row in the foreign table.

I normally just have no default for the foreign key and if there is no link to a row in the foreign table then the foreign key is null. This is legal because you have defined all the foreign keys as nullable